# Is there a Fabric-CA API for register ( without using User instance)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to use Fabric Node SDK  (CA) to register identities. I noticed MSP ID/User Instance is must in order to register. However , I am able to do the same without MSPID using CLI fabri-ca-client

These are the steps followed in using CLI

**Enrolling CA-Client user (using the bootstrap)**

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://hotel_admin:password@fabric-ca:7054 -c $HOME//CA-INFRA/client/config.yaml --tls.certfiles  $HOME//CA-INFRA/server/tls-server/cert.pem
```

**Register user for different Orgs**

```
fabric-ca-client register -u "https://fabric-ca:7054" --id.name "hotel_admin:password" --id.secret "password" --id.type "app" --id.attrs '"Role=ADMIN:ecert","Dept=BOOKING_UNIT:ecert","Org=HOTEL:ecert"' -c "$HOME//CA-INFRA/client/config.yaml" --tls.certfiles  $HOME/loyalty_solutions/CA-INFRA/server/tls-server/cert.pem
```

**Enrolling user for the above Orgs**

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u "https://hotel_admin:password@fabric-ca:7054"  --tls.certfiles  $HOME//CA-INFRA/server/tls-server/cert.pem -M $HOME//CA-INFRA/hotel_msp_admin
```

**Looking at the regitration APIS**

```
Class : FabricCAServices
API : register(req, registrar) 
This requires registrar ( nothing but the User instance which is set using Fabric Client)
```

All I am trying to do is interact between Fabric-CA-Server and Fabric-CA-CLient using API's but there doesnt seem to be a way. However, it is possible through CLI

Note:
- I have no affiliations set up in server. we are achieving the access control via special attributes